# Get option values from category field in podio Java API

Tags: podio, java

I have a `Podio` app with category field and some option values in it. I want to get all the category option values from `Podio` using `Java API`.
Is there any way to get it ?
[My podio app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgqvq.png)

Answer (score 3):

You will get the Podio app config by calling a GET request to `/app/{app_id}` endpoint.

Refer Podio API Doc [here](https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349)

You can also try this operation in the sandbox on that doc page.